# Excel FTP Power Query getting no data on one computer

Tags: microsoft-excel, ftp, power-query

I have long used the following simple Excel FTP query to populate a Table.  As shown in Power Query Editor:

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(Web.Contents("ftp://shortstock@ftp3.interactivebrokers.com/usa.txt"),[Delimiter="|", Columns=9, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])
in
    Source
```

Suddenly today it gets no data (i.e., "0 rows loaded."), but a colleague on a different computer at a different location running that same query does get data (~15k rows).  Any ideas on how to debug this failure to get data on this one computer?  Among the things I have tried:

1. Confirm that I can get that file via FTP from the same computer using Filezilla, suggesting it's not a firewall problem.
2. Opening ports 20-21 in Windows Defender.
3. [Repairing Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b).
4. Rolling back Office to the Build prior to last week (when Microsoft pushed a new build).

Answer (score 0):

TBH it's a bit wild to me that this ever worked, but cool.

Perhaps the issue is in the authentication? The credentials are cached in your windows profile, but might have changed or expired.

From the Data ribbon, go to **Get Data / Data Source Settings**, choose your entry and hit **Edit Permissions**.

Comment: I just followed that to clear all "permissions" in Excel, then refreshing this source I still get nothing.  (Note that this FTP site returns that file using only that username; no password required.)